# auto redirect a page on visibilitystate with javascript

Tags: javascript, visibility

i'm working on a small sale website. i want to use visibilitystate to dictate when the user navigates to a new page, switches tabs, closes the tab, minimizes or closes the browser, or, on mobile, switches from the browser to a different app. to return a new URL. `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {`
`if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {`
`setTimeout(function(){`
`window.location.href = 'www.google.com';`
 `}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

1. for unload tab or tab close , then prompt

   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
   alert("The window is closing now!");
   });
2. if want to detect tab switch then,

   document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
   if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
   console.log("tab is active")
   } else {
   console.log("tab is inactive")
   }
   });